# How to iterate through shared_ptr vector

Tags: c++

I have a vector:

```
vector<MyClass> database;
```

and a second one:

```
vector<shared_ptr<MyClass> > databasePtrs;
```

`databasePtrs` contains pointers to database elements in a certain order. I want to iterate through the pointers using an iterator, not `for` cycle. But I have no idea how to create the iterator.  The expression:

```
vector<MyClass>::iterator it;
```

obviously doesn't work, nor do other variants I've tried.

Comment: `vector<shared_ptr<MyClass>>::iterator` is the obvious approach.

Comment: Use `auto` ? or directly *for range*.

Comment: I'd say `for (const auto& ptr : databasePtrs)` would be the obvious approach, but if you *insist* on using iterators directly then `for (auto it = databasePtrs.begin(); it != databasePtrs.end(); ++it)`.

Comment: Not to the question, but are you having a bunch of shared pointers referring to the elements of the vector (your `database`)? If that's true than you are probably missing the point of `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have no idea, how to create the iterator.

You can get the iterator to the first element of the vector using `std::vector::begin`.

> ```
> vector<MyClass>::iterator it;
> ```

You cannot use that iterator to iterate a `vector<shared_ptr<MyClass> >`. You need a `vector<shared_ptr<MyClass> >::iterator` instead.

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed, thanks. I've probably tried it already, but I couldn't access MyClass methods using this iterator back then.